# TextView Not Showing Text

Tags: android

I'm something of an Android noob, and for the life of me, I can't work out why my TextView isn't showing.

Here's my Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:context="com.petastapleton.tapintoabetteryou.MainActivity" 
android:background="@color/light_gray">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/accent_blue" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Hello"
         />     
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/mid_gray">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                    
            android:layout_span="2"
         />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/accent_blue">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                    
            android:layout_span="2"
         />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ideally, I should have some white words in the top-row of my table - instead, the row expands slightly, indicating something happened there, but there's no words.

Screenshot below (from Eclipse, but even emulated with AVD it doesn't change anything)

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Comment: clean and run the project once more??

Comment: post xml and code, and if getting any warning then post logcat

Comment: XML's there now, my code is stock, no changes to it from default.

Comment: You have no text in it.  With no text, it will have 0 height thus be invisible.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have `android:text="Hello"` - doesn't that work?

Comment: I must have missed it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @GabeSechan that's okay! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give orientation as

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

in `<TableRow>`

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead 0dp

Remove `android:layout_span="2"`

Comment: Thanks! It was the layout_span!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Hello"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Hello"
         />
```

to

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row1"


            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Hello"
         />
```

Comment: That just insists I add those attributes back in

Answer (score 0):

You mention WeightSum but you dont mention WeightSum in layout. Which weight you want to divide in another  weight sum. In parent layout give the WeightSum then add weight sum and then give the weight to all text and made height 0dp.

You want to make it Genric layout so put weightSum in Parent layout that break the screen in 2-2inch of partition and then put weight to all UI widget and in UI widget height made 0dp.

In Table Gives Weight Sum and complete the Weight in UI of child of Table WeightSum.

---

This was about layout but you text not show after this then set Margin or Alignment because your text is going out side of the screen.